# How to make D3 display xAxis correctly during daylight saving time change

Tags: javascript, d3.js, timezone, render, dst

I am creating line charts from data using D3. 
I am using D3's d3.svg.axis() passing in .tickValues
Everything works fine until the start / end times of my chart cross over the change in daylight saving, e.g. Sun 30th October this year @ 02:00am.
Then I am not able to get he xaXis to show as I would like it to.
If I change the .tickValues half way through (e.g. after 2 am) then it simply creates a big gap (october) or the values overlap (april).
The chart lines themselves continue to render just fine. It's only a problem with the xAxis. This ought to be just a cosmetic change but it may well go deeper than this. Right now I would just like the chart to render the lines as it does, but see the xAxis appear nice and smooth like this

01:57  01:58  01:59  01:00  01:01  01:02

or like this in the summer

01:57  01:58  01:59  03:00  03:01  03:01

...withtout it rendering the scale ticks overlapping each other or being subjected to a large space!

Comment: A picture would be nice, if you would edit your question.  But also, the axis itself would have to be altered, because local time is non-linear at the discontinuities of DST transitions. I'm not sure if D3 can do that or not.

Answer (score 1):

...the answer in the end was to implement a custom tick format function and pass this into `d3.svg.axis().tickFormat(myCustomTickFormatFunction)`